# How do I display a function using setTimeout in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, timer, settimeout

I have made a quiz with JavaScript and want that when the timer is up, it should not let you attempt the quiz anymore and go to the last page which displays the score. The score is displayed by calling `displayResult`. I have one HTML file and one JS file. When I use `setTimeout`, even after the time is up, it doesn’t show the score. I think the function doesn’t get called. I have tried using `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` but still it doesn't work.  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

[Whole code here.](https://jsfiddle.net/0g95mycv/)

```js
//timer code in quiz.js

   

const startingMinutes = 1
let time = startingMinutes * 60
const countdownEl = document.getElementById('countdown')
var vri = setInterval(upd, 1000)

function upd() {
  const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60)
  let seconds = time % 60
  
  seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds
  countdownEl.innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds
  time--
  time = time < 0 ? 0 : time
  
  if (time == 0) {
    clearInterval(vri);
  }
  
  setTimeout(displayResult, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mre] (this means, your _code must be in the question itself)_, and demonstrate _your research and your attempts_ (e.g. debugging) and explain what precisely didn’t work. The code in your JSFiddle shows several linter and HTML validation warnings, including `if(correct = 0`…`)` being equivalent to `if(false)`. Fix these _before_ asking a question, please.

Comment: Currently, you are calling `upd()` every second. This function creates a one second timeout then executes `displayResult()`. So, `displayResult()` is being executed once every second until `time===0`... That's a lot of complicated mechanisms, why not just a simple `setTimeout(displayResult, time*1000)` ?

Comment: I tried setTimeout(displayResult, time*1000) still nothing happened

Comment: @TEHREEMHASNAIN the function gets called as you can check when console.log inside it. The problem is that you have to append the score to your body or maybe the better solution you Replace the bodys elements to only show the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function gets called you can easily check this by inserting a `console.log()` inside the function.

When you would like to display the results on the same page then first clear the body and append your new created element on the body.

There is still a bug that your selected elements will always be empty but I just answer your question here "How you display it."

For debugging purposes I set the timer to 6 seconds instead of 60.

```js
(function() {
  var allQuestions = [{
    question: "The tree sends downroots from its branches to the soil is know as:",
    options: ["Oak", "Pine", "Banyan", "Palm"],
    answer: 2
  }, {
    question: "Electric bulb filament is made of",
    options: ["Copper", "Aluminum", "lead", "Tungsten"],
    answer: 3
  }, {
    question: "Non Metal that remains liquid at room temprature is",
    options: ["Phophorous", "Bromine", "Clorine", "Helium"],
    answer: 1
  }, {
    question: "Which of the following is used in Pencils ?",
    options: ["Graphite", "Silicon", "Charcoal", "Phosphorous"],
    answer: 0
  }, {
    question: "Chemical formula of water ?",
    options: ["NaA1O2", "H2O", "Al2O3", "CaSiO3"],
    answer: 1
  }, {
    question: "The gas filled in electric bulb is ?",
    options: ["Nitrogen", "Hydrogen", "Carbon Dioxide", "Oxygen"],
    answer: 0
  }, {
    question: "Whashing soda is the comman name for",
    options: ["Sodium Carbonate", "Calcium Bicarbonate", "Sodium Bicarbonate", "Calcium Carbonate"],
    answer: 0
  }, {
    question: "Which gas is not known as green house gas ?",
    options: ["Methane", "Nitrous oxide", "Carbon Dioxide", "Hydrogen"],
    answer: 3
  }, {
    question: "The hardest substance availabe on earth is",
    options: ["Gold", "Iron", "Diamond", "Platinum"],
    answer: 2
  }, {
    question: "Used as a lubricant",
    options: ["Graphite", "Silica", "Iron Oxide", "Diamond"],
    answer: 0
  }];

  var quesCounter = 0;
  var selectOptions = [];
  var quizSpace = $('#quiz');



  nextQuestion();

  $('#next').click(function() {
    chooseOption();
    if (isNaN(selectOptions[quesCounter])) {
      alert('Please select an option !');
    } else {
      quesCounter += 5;
      nextQuestion();
    }
  });

  $('#prev').click(function() {
    chooseOption();
    quesCounter -= 5;
    nextQuestion();
  });

  function createElement(index) {
    var element = $('<div>', {
      id: 'question'
    });
    var header = $('<h2>Question No. ' + (index + 1) + ' :</h2>');
    element.append(header);

    var question = $('<p>').append(allQuestions[index].question);
    element.append(question);
    var radio = radioButtons(index);
    element.append(radio);


    var question1 = $('<p>').append(allQuestions[index + 1].question);
    element.append(question1);
    var radio1 = radioButtons1(index + 1);
    element.append(radio1);


    var question2 = $('<p>').append(allQuestions[index + 2].question);
    element.append(question2);
    var radio2 = radioButtons2(index + 2);
    element.append(radio2);


    var question3 = $('<p>').append(allQuestions[index + 3].question);
    element.append(question3);
    var radio3 = radioButtons3(index + 3);
    element.append(radio3);

    var question4 = $('<p>').append(allQuestions[index + 4].question);
    element.append(question4);

    var radio4 = radioButtons4(index + 4);
    element.append(radio4);




    return element;
  }

  function radioButtons(index) {
    var radioItems = $('<ul>');
    var item;
    var input = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < allQuestions[index].options.length; i++) {
      item = $('<li>');
      input = '<input type="radio" name="answer" value=' + i + ' />';
      input += allQuestions[index].options[i];
      item.append(input);
      radioItems.append(item);

    }
    return radioItems;
  }

  function radioButtons1(index) {
    var radioItems1 = $('<ul>');
    var item1;
    var input1 = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < allQuestions[index].options.length; i++) {
      item1 = $('<li>');
      input1 = '<input type="radio" name="answer1" value=' + i + ' />';
      input1 += allQuestions[index].options[i];
      item1.append(input1);
      radioItems1.append(item1);

    }
    return radioItems1;
  }

  function radioButtons2(index) {
    var radioItems2 = $('<ul>');
    var item2;
    var input2 = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < allQuestions[index].options.length; i++) {
      item2 = $('<li>');
      input2 = '<input type="radio" name="answer2" value=' + i + ' />';
      input2 += allQuestions[index].options[i];
      item2.append(input2);
      radioItems2.append(item2);

    }
    return radioItems2;
  }

  function radioButtons3(index) {
    var radioItems3 = $('<ul>');
    var item3;
    var input3 = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < allQuestions[index].options.length; i++) {
      item3 = $('<li>');
      input3 = '<input type="radio" name="answer3" value=' + i + ' />';
      input3 += allQuestions[index].options[i];
      item3.append(input3);
      radioItems3.append(item3);

    }
    return radioItems3;
  }

  function radioButtons4(index) {
    var radioItems4 = $('<ul>');
    var item4;
    var input4 = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < allQuestions[index].options.length; i++) {
      item4 = $('<li>');
      input4 = '<input type="radio" name="answer4" value=' + i + ' />';
      input4 += allQuestions[index].options[i];
      item4.append(input4);
      radioItems4.append(item4);

    }
    return radioItems4;
  }

  function chooseOption() {
    selectOptions[quesCounter] = +$('input[name="answer"]:checked').val();
    selectOptions[quesCounter + 1] = +$('input[name="answer1"]:checked').val();
    selectOptions[quesCounter + 2] = +$('input[name="answer2"]:checked').val();
    selectOptions[quesCounter + 3] = +$('input[name="answer3"]:checked').val();
    selectOptions[quesCounter + 4] = +$('input[name="answer4"]:checked').val();
  }

  function nextQuestion() {
    quizSpace.fadeOut(function() {
      $('#question').remove();
      if (quesCounter < allQuestions.length) {
        var nextQuestion = createElement(quesCounter);
        quizSpace.append(nextQuestion).fadeIn();
        if (!(isNaN(selectOptions[quesCounter, quesCounter + 1, quesCounter + 2, quesCounter + 3, quesCounter + 4]))) {
          $('input[value=' + selectOptions[quesCounter] + ']').prop('checked', true);
          $('input[value=' + selectOptions[quesCounter + 1] + ']').prop('checked', true);
          $('input[value=' + selectOptions[quesCounter + 2] + ']').prop('checked', true);
          $('input[value=' + selectOptions[quesCounter + 3] + ']').prop('checked', true);
          $('input[value=' + selectOptions[quesCounter + 4] + ']').prop('checked', true);


        }
        if (quesCounter === 1) {
          $('#prev').show();
        } else if (quesCounter === 0) {
          $('#prev').hide();
          $('#next').show();
        }
      } else {
        var scoreRslt = displayResult();
        quizSpace.append(scoreRslt).fadeIn();
        $('#next').hide();
        $('#prev').hide();
      }
    });
  }

  const startingMinutes = 0.1;
  let time = startingMinutes * 60
  const countdownEl = document.getElementById('countdown')
  var vri = setInterval(upd, 1000)

  function upd() {
    const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60)
    let seconds = time % 60
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds
    countdownEl.innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds
    time--
    time = time < 0 ? 0 : time
    console.log(time);
    if (time === 0) {
      clearInterval(vri);
      setTimeout(displayResult, 1000);
    }

  }


  function displayResult() {

    console.log(selectOptions);
    var correct = 0;
    console.log(selectOptions);
    for (var i = 0; i < selectOptions.length; i++) {
      if (selectOptions[i] === allQuestions[i].answer) {
        correct++;
      }
    }

    document.body.innerHTML = "";
    let score = document.createElement("p");
    score.id = 'question';
    if (correct === 0 && correct <= 5) {
      let otherText = document.createTextNode("YOUR IQ SCORES LIES IN THE RANGE OF 70 and 79 WHICH IS CLASSIFIED AS BORDERLINE");
      let img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = "img9b.png"


      score.append(otherText)
      score.append(img);
    } else {
      let tex = document.createTextNode("The Result is: " + correct);
      score.appendChild(tex);

    }
    document.body.appendChild(score);

  }
})();
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Make Quiz Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="quiz.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <h1>Quiz Website Using JavaScript</h1>
    <br/>
    <div id="quiz"></div>
    <p id="countdown">30:00</p>
    </h1>
    <div class="button" id="next"><a href="#">Next</a></div>
    <div class="button" id="prev"><a href="#">Prev</a></div>
  </div>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="quiz.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```